# Apply a Transform to a UIView Itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, catransform3d

I'm trying to apply a perspective transform to my UIView object with the following code:

```
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
t.m34 = -1.0/1000;
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

myView.layer.transform = t;
```

and I don't see any effect at all. I tried other transforms like a simple translation and they don't work either.

However, if I do either of the following two modifications then it will work somewhat but neither satisfies my request:

1. Change the last line to

   myView.layer.sublayerTransform = t;

This sort of works but it only transforms the subviews on myView, not myView itself.

1. Add an animation code to apply the change instead of directly assign the change to the layer:

   CABasicAnimation *turningAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
   turningAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t];
   turningAnimation.delegate = self;
   turningAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
   turningAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

   [myView.layer addAnimation:turningAnimation forKey:@"turning"];

The thing is that I don't want the animation.

Can anybody point a direction for me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the angle you provided?

Comment: It's an arbitrary angle, such as 45.0f * M_PI/180.0

Comment: It does work for me with any arbitrary angle...

Comment: Just want to make sure you used myView.layer.transform instead of myView.layer.sublayerTransform, and you didn't use animation?

Comment: I did not use animation and did set the transform to the view's layer and not the sublayers

Comment: I started a blank project and added the minimum code and tested the above transform and it does work. So I think there must be something else in my (original) project that prevented the view from turning. I'll have to dig into it to find out. Thanks for your patient testing and reply!

Comment: I figured out the problem. It is because my view's layer has a previous animation which has a toValue equal to identity transform and removedOnCompletion equal to NO, thus preventing subsequent non-animated transform from working. Thanks again, your test confirmed to me that the transform on layer itself does work so I could concentrate on checking other parts of code.

Comment: welcome CodePlumber ..Add this as an answer and mark it answered..

Comment: Did as you suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem after test by Krishnan confirmed that layer.transform itself does work without the aid of animation or sublayerTransform. The problem I encountered was caused by an animation that had been applied to my view's layer and was not subsequently removed. Since this animation had a toValue equal to the identity transform, I didn't realize it can actually prevent subsequent non-animated transforms from working. Setting removedOnCompletion = YES (which is default) on the animation solved the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle).  It won't animate the property unless you explicitly tell it to using [UIView animateWithDuration:].  Using the UIView transform property will ultimately apply your transformation to the CALayer that backs UIView, so I would make sure to only interact with the transforms on one level (UIView or CALayer).

UIView transform doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform

CGAffineTransform Doc:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but CGAffineTransform is only for 2D linear transform. I need 3D projections, such as the perspective transform I put in the question.